# Repeat First element of a List of Lists Based on Length

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list of lists:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

What I want is to repeat the first element of each list based on the length of the list:

```
result = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

I can achieve this using list comprehension but my list is very long and so the method is slow:

```
result = [[x[0]]*len(x) for x in l]

[[1, 1, 1], [4], [5, 5], [7, 7, 7, 7]]
```

Although, this still returns a list of lists rather than a flat list. So, I am trying to figure out the fastest method for creating that flat list based on the criteria mentioned above.

**Update**: I want the fastest performing method since the list is long

Comment: *I want the fastest performing method since the list is long* Hopefully the other answers are not outcast!

Comment: I added the update but the original post clearly mentioned that my solution was slow. How about editing your answer(s) to take this point into account?

Comment: Brother do note that this is for the community as a whole. So we answer thinking of future users also. But remember to accept only that answer which you feel is the best. :). (Numerous answers will come later on after a few years)

Comment: Do you actually need all the elements at once?

Comment: @Bhargav: I agree with you. It wasn't me who down-voted as I too value alternative answers and educational answers.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I'm not sure I understand where you are going with your question. I will be pushing all of the elements into a Pandas dataframe if that helps?

Comment: I mean if you are using an element at a time why create a full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.repeat` with `chain` is the most efficient using python 2:

```
In [13]: l = [choice(l) for _ in xrange(1000000)]
In [14]: timeit list(itertools.chain(*[[i[0]]*len(i) for i in l]))
1 loops, best of 3: 416 ms per loop

In [15]: timeit [i[0] for i in l for _ in xrange(len(i))]
1 loops, best of 3: 245 ms per loop

In [16]: timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(repeat(i[0],len(i)) for i in l))
1 loops, best of 3: 223 ms per loop

In [17]: timeit [i for x in l for i in [x[0]]*len(x)]
1 loops, best of 3: 332 ms per loop
```

Interestingly using  `python3`, using a list instead of a generator expression is faster:

```
In [8]: timeit list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i[0], len(i)) for i in l))
1 loops, best of 3: 372 ms per loop

In [9]: timeit [i[0] for i in l for _ in range(len(i))]
1 loops, best of 3: 433 ms per loop

In [10]: timeit list(chain.from_iterable([repeat(i[0],len(i)) for i in l]))
1 loops, best of 3: 296 ms per loop

In [11]: timeit list(chain(*[[i[0]]*len(i) for i in l]))
1 loops, best of 3: 460 ms per loop

In [12]: timeit [i for x in l for i in [x[0]]*len(x)]
1 loops, best of 3: 348 ms per loop
```

If you want a compromise between time and space then iterate over the chain object getting an element at a time:

```
In [18]: %%timeit
for ele in chain.from_iterable([repeat(i[0],len(i)) for i in l]):
        pass
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 306 ms per lo
```

Comment: Small request. Can you please try `timeit` on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28988828/4099593) and comment back with the results? (Would have done it by myself if I was on comp) *Sorry to disturb* :(

Comment: @BhargavRao, no worries, I don't think you will like the result though!

Comment: I'm guessing it to be over 1000ms

Comment: @BhargavRao, you can probably remove the `m` ;)

Comment: Damn! There are two `lambda`s and two calls and three list formations! But without the `m` ... Srsly, then it is as slow as IE

Comment: @BhargavRao, for `10000` it took `421 ms` for `100000` I had to stop both after a few minutes so `1000000` is also not going to happen!

Comment: Hey! How bout I remove the `m` as you said and put `M` there? *But* if the OP ever tried that method he would be so damn pissed off! I better add a disclaimer there ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten your result.

```
import itertools
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
res = list(itertools.chain(*[[i[0]]*len(i) for i in l]))
print (res)
```

Yields:

```
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

---

As per **@PadraicCunningham** suggestion, can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` which is faster than `itertools.chain` in comparision.

```
import timeit
case1 = lambda: list(itertools.chain(*[[i[0]]*len(i) for i in l]))
case2 = lambda: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i[0]]*len(i) for i in l]))

print ("time required by Case1 to execute :", timeit.timeit(case1))
print ("time required by Case1 to execute :", timeit.timeit(case2))
```

Shows the time report for both the cases:

```
time required by Case1 to execute : 4.83640388816
time required by Case1 to execute : 4.68654976762
```

Comment: Great answer using builtins. As a suggestion, put brackets around `res` in `print res` JIC the OP is using py3.

Comment: `chain.from_iterable` is usually faster

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Could you edit this answer to include a corresponding implementation using chain.from_iterable, please?

Comment: `itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i[0]]*len(i) for i in l])` will do the same thing. That is basically what  `chain*` is doing but I have always found using `from_iterable` to be faster

Comment: Would I still have to wrap the results in a list()?  list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(...))

Comment: @PadraicCunningham : Thanks for informing about `.from_iterable`, I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Thanks for the suggestion of print function.

Comment: @TanveerAlam Np. Anytime!. remember this advice always anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [i[0] for i in l for _ in range(len(i))]
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Comment: @BhargavRao thanks! unfortunately still there is 2 down vote! :( the guys became very fast nowadays! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this,

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> [i for x in l for i in [x[0]]*len(x)]
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Comment: [leaf for tree in forest for leaf in tree] = for tree in forest, for leaf in tree, return leaf

Answer (score 1):

The rest of the answers are very good. Here is an *alternative* answer<sup>1</sup> using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,map(lambda x:[x[0]]*len(x),l))
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>So that you can learn new python modules.</sub>

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988544/repeat-first-element-of-a-list-of-lists-based-on-length/28988828#comment46229506_28989874) This is the worst of all the answers in terms of time complexity! So beware ;)